# Points of a triangle in the Python Manim Library?

Tags: python, manim

So I am doing some pythagorean theorem related things with manim but I need to get each point of the triangle so I can add a, b, c on each point but how do I do that?

```
class Pythagorean(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        triangle = Polygon(np.array([0,-2,2]),np.array([2,2,0]),np.array([2,-2,0]), run_time=2, color=lightyellow).move_to(0.5*LEFT)
        triangle.set_fill(lighteryellow, opacity=1.0)
        self.add(triangle)
        self.play(Write(triangle))
        self.wait(3)
```

Comment: why do you need Numpy arrays?

Comment: @riov8 The size and position of the triangle.

Comment: what do you mean by "add a,b,c on each point?"

Comment: @angrymantis So it shows a on a point, b on another, and c on the last.